# How can I create a new custom page with my own content in Elgg

Tags: plugins, elgg

I would like to create a new page in Elgg where I can put my own content. I would like to have there all the default menus, etc. but with empty space where I can put my code. I would like to have a link to this page on my profile page. Should it be done as a new plugin? If yes, how to create empty page with my current template settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/How_do_I_create_a_new_page%3F

Comment: this is not suporting now, can you please update the like with a new one